# Function that returns true if string is a pronoun

Tags: php, string

I am trying to build a function that returns true if a given string, as an argument, is a pronoun.

I figured a good way to do this is to check if it begins with a capital / uppercase letter.

If you know of a better what to tell if something is a pronoun, please let me know.

But, for the checking if the first letter is a capital / upper case letter, how can I do that.

I know `string[0`] would give me the first letter, but what do I compare it to to check if it is any capital / upper case letter in the alphabet?

The code that I have right now is

```
function isPronoun($str){
    $result = false;
    if($str[0]===/*capital letter*/){
        $result=true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: pronoun or proper noun

Comment: do you mean proper noun? Washington/Johnson/Obama is a proper noun, he/she/it is a pronoun. Also, not all proper nouns start with a capital letter: iPhone, iPod, iTunes, etc

Comment: what if string contains more than 1 words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper nouns such as "Mark", "London" or "Betelgeuse" also begin with a capital letter, as does the first word of a sentence, while "he" or "it" are pronouns that begin with a lowercase letter.

To identify a pronoun, you need a language parser such as a [Brill Parser](http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging).

Comment: +1 for "Betelgeuse" - would've been better combined with "Ford" though :p

Comment: Ah, okay. Can you add to the example how to use Brill Parser to find out if it is a pronoun?

Comment: I mean proper noun. How would I use this to detect if a word is a proper noun. Can you please provide me with an example? This seems like it tags the words in its dictionary and there is a noun tag, but not a proper noun tag. How do I get it to find proper nouns?

Comment: The brill parser should tag a proper noun as /NNP

Answer (score 0):

try with regular expression

```
function isPronoun($str){
         return ereg("^[A-Z]", $str);
}
```

Comment: This matches things like THIS, but not This.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "Proper Noun", not pronoun. Pronouns are things like "I", "you"...

Anyway, try something like this:

```
$is_proper_noun = preg_match("(^[A-Z]\w+$)",$word);
```

Note that you can make this more elaborate, for instance:

```
"(^(?:Ma?c|O')?[A-Z][a-z]+$)"
```

Comment: What does the second regex do? I can't understand that one.

Comment: The second regex is basically intended to only allow the first letter to be uppercase, and all other letters should be lowercase, as is the case of proper nouns over (among other things) acronyms. The extra bit at the start allows names like "McDonald", "MacGuffin" or "O'Reilley" - note that it's still not complete, for instance it won't allow Al'Sudiary, or DiNozzo.